# Counting number of occurrences in a row

Tags: python

If a have a list of n booleans, what would be the best way to find how many times true appears in a list once in a row, two times in a row and so on?

For an example:
list1 = [True,False,True, True, False, False, False, True,True]

true appears once in row once, and two times in a row twice.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `your_list.count(True)`

Comment: What do you mean by "once in a row", "two times in a row"? By any chance do you have a list of lists?

Comment: I think OP by that mean consecutively @Valentino

Comment: @Damian That doesn't do what the OP is asking, though.

Comment: @yatu I see... that is possible. But the question should be made clearer in my opinion. We are guessing here.

Comment: yes, indeed @Valentino

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to find consecutive occurrences of `Trues` and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Lets try with the following list:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

l = [True, False, True, True, True, True, False, True]
Counter(sum(v) for k,v in groupby(l) if k)
# Counter({1: 2, 4: 1})
```

Comment: You can also just use `sum(v)` without building a list first, since each `True` value contributes 1 to the sum.

Comment: Hmmm but I think OP wants to count how many times it appears consecutively `i` times, for `i` in `1.....n`

Comment: No, I just mean that `len(list(v)) == sum(v)` if `v` is a generator that produces only the boolean value `True` some number of times.